# Returning large size response from Rest API in Spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, rest

I am working on a Rest API in my Spring boot application. Here response size is considerably large from 10 MB -100 MB.

Initially, I implemented the API as follows:

```
 @GetMapping("/document/state")
  public ResponseEntity<String> getLucidChartDocumentState(
      @RequestParam(required = true, name = "documentId") String documentId) throws IOException {
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
        .body(lucidChartDocumentService.getDocumentState(documentId).getBody());
  }
```

I am not sure if returning the response as a Response is a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you wouldn't load content of the file into a memory or you'll quickly run out of it even with relatively load traffic.

If your service class returns an `InputStream` you can wrap it into [InputStreamResource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/InputStreamResource.html) and return in a response body. Note: you should have way to get the content length of the object without reading it to byte array.

```java
InputStreamResource inputStreamResource = new InputStreamResource(inputStream);
httpHeaders.setContentLength(contentLength);
return new ResponseEntity(inputStreamResource, httpHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have one doubt here: if I don't pass content length here, will be any problem on the client side?